# Jquery Ajax POST method using GET instead of POST?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, go

Ok so i have this html login page for a test website:

```
<body>
    <div class = "container-login">
        <form class ="devbook-form" id ="login">
            <span>
                Welcome to Devbook!
            </span>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required="required">
            </div>
            <div> 
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required="required">
            </div>
            <a href="/register">Register Here</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-devbook">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The scripts calls for the js responsible for communication with an API, but it simply doesnt start the Ajax, or the Ajax is working in the wrong way, but must probably it doesnt start the Ajax cause i tried to put a console.log("Testing") in the button but the consoles gives nothing. I have another ajax button for another html page which works perfectly, why is that?

This is the Ajax Jquery i'm using to get the form for a login button:

```
$('#login').on('submit', loginAccount);

function loginAccount(event){
    event.PreventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:"/login",
        method:"POST",
        data: {
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
        }
    }).done(function() {
        window.location = "/home";
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("Invalid email or password");
    });
}
```

All this is meant to communicate with an API working on localhost:3000, which was made with Golang using GIN framework, it has an public.POST("/login", controllers.LoginAccount) which is meant to communicate with another API. The html page, jquery ajax and register golang function all works, but the login it doesnt, it always performs a GET instead of a POST, why is that?

Comment: I don't believe you're actually getting to the ajax call.  `form` defaults to `GET` absent an action.  also your `button` is type `submit`, and should be `button` and then you should be capturing the button click not trying to prevent the default submit action

Comment: that's weird, the teacher did the exact same button and html page and works fine for him, its async course, so i cant ask him right now what's wrong, but why it doesnt work for the login page but its exactly the ''same'' in the register page and it works? The /assets/js/login.js is where's stored that ajax call

Comment: you can but you have to set the action to POST, capture $(form).submit(), make your ajax call and be sure to return false;

Comment: fount [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967066/how-do-you-override-an-existing-html-form-to-use-jquery-to-post-the-form) on SO

Comment: Thanks, i've been reading but even if i change the ajax coding it does nothing to the button, the button still tries to perform a GET, what should i change in the html? It doesnt even ''preventDefault'' as it should, not even a console.log if i try

Comment: your `button`, if it's set to `type=submit`, will use the `form` action attribute, which defaults to GET. And since a GET is what you see, seems to me to say that your ajax call is not being hit at all.  a simple breakpoint at the top of your function should quickly tell you if that code is even being hit.  Also make sure your  jquery event setup is inside the jquery ready handler

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` Not `event.PreventDefault();`

Comment: That's it! It's solved! Thank you! Wrote it with capital letter due to my manners with golang, thank you!